# Why does the enclosed code generate a 'ValueError' rather than a 'TypeError'?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

This is regarding an Intro to Python academic course exercise on expections.  I had originally posted this question onto the course's Canvas discussion board, but there hasn't been a single reply (not even from the professor), so I've decided to post it up here to see if it'll fare better.

**Here's the assignment prompt:**

```
In-Class Exercise on Exceptions

Q1. Generate correct output for following code. 

1.Try letter m (not an integer)
2.Try 12 for the first number then 0 for the second number
3.Try 12 for the first number then 3 for the second number. Then explain why you have Unknown error at the end of the output

try:
    userInput1 = int(input("Please enter an Integer:"))
    userInput2 = int(input("Please enter another Integer:"))
    answer = userInput1/userInput2
    print("The answer is", answer)
    myFile = open("missing.txt", 'r')
except ValueError:
    print("Error: You did not enter a number")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Error: Cannot Divide by Zero")
except Exception as e:
    print("Unknown Error: ", e)
```

**Here's the code I wrote for the exercise:**

```
def div_calc(num1, num2):
    try:
#        num1 = int(input("Please enter an Integer: "))
#        num2 = int(input("Please enter another Integer: "))
        answer = num1/num2
        print("The answer is", answer)
        myFile = open("missing.txt", 'r')
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: You did not enter a number")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Error: Cannot Divide by Zero")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unknown Error: ", e)
#   Q1.1
# Could not trigger as function, so "m" has to be entered manually on prompt
try:
    num1 = int(input("Please enter an Integer: "))
    num2 = int(input("Please enter another Integer: "))
    answer = num1/num2
    print("The answer is", answer)
    myFile = open("missing.txt", 'r')
except ValueError:
    print("Error: You did not enter a number")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Error: Cannot Divide by Zero")
except Exception as e:
    print("Unknown Error: ", e)

#   Q1.2
div_calc(12, 0)

#Q1.3
div_calc(12, 3)
print("\'Exception as e\' caused by \'myFile = open(\"missing.txt\", \'r\')\' when \n no such file exists.")
```

My question as it was posted on the course's Canvas board:

> Why does entering "m" in scenario 1 trip a ValueError instead of a TypeError?
> According to the official Python v3.11.3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html):
> ...Passing arguments of the wrong type (e.g. passing a listLinks to an external site. when an intLinks to an external site. is expected) should result in a TypeErrorLinks to an external site., but passing arguments with the wrong value (e.g. a number outside expected boundaries) should result in a ValueErrorLinks to an external site....
> Furthermore, when I attempted to define the code as a function and the inputs as arguments...

> Feeding the function "m" for either of (or both) parameters throws Exception as e referencing "Unknown Error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'" (or ...'str' and 'str')
> I wasn't able to get the function to throw the exception when defining and giving only a single parameter and argument, as it continues on to ask for the second input, which results in one of the aforementioned Error as e exceptions.
> When defining and giving two parameters with one argument I get "TypeError: div_calc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'userInput2'"

Comment: `int` expects an object of type `str` to convert it to an int. The error is the content (value) of the string. A division where one object is not of a numerical type would never make sense, regardless of the value of e. g. the string.

Comment: Well, `int('m')` raises a `ValueError`, because `"m"` is a string, and `int` works fine with strings. It's just a bad coincidence that the string has a wrong value inside, thus a `ValueError`. Furthermore, `int('m', 36)` (just a sufficiently large base) will succeed, so a `TypeError` would be definitely wrong here.

Comment: You might be confused about what “type” means (or maybe specifically how types work in Python).  The result of calling `input()` always has type `str`; it doesn’t change based on what you enter.  If `float()` didn’t expect an argument of type `str` you could *never* call it with the result you get from `input()`, regardless of what they entered.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Ahh, I see.  So that means I should have written the `answer` variable declaration as `answer = int(num1)/int(num2)` instead and it would have behaved as expected, everything else being the same?

Comment: Calling `int('m')` will raise a ValueError regardless of what you plan to do with the result afterward.

Comment: @Samwise Yes, I understand now, I was thrown off that it kept giving the TypeError instead of the ValueError, but I'm beginning to see what everyone means when they say Python is very pedantic.  Basically it doesn't matter that 'm' isn't a valid int(), what matters is an int()  was what was expected at that line and the value it was fed couldn't be converted appropriately, correct?

Comment: I’m not following your explanation.  The thing that raises the error is the `int` function.  It raises the error because the value of the string you passed it was not something that could be translated into an int (ie a decimal representation of an int).

Comment: @Samwise Sorry I'm not conveying it very well, but I do get it.  While I was doing the assignment, despite the numerous times I was staring directly them, I just glossed over the `int()`.  In retrospect, I think I was just too focused on the values themselves (plus lack of sleep), but it just goes to make me appreciate how literal and sequential Python is, that's what I was trying to point out in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice from the documentation, for int the expected parameter is an object.

```
>>> help(int)
Help on class int in module builtins:

class int(object)
 |  int([x]) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
 |  numbers, this truncates towards zero.
 |  
 |  If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
 |  bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
 |  given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
 |  by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
 |  Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
 |  >>> int('0b100', base=0)
 |  4
```

Note a key point in python is everything is an object.
Help (int) states the type of objects acceptable to int().
If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
|  bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
|  given base.

So all objects which are not the accepted types will produce a TypeError.
input() returns a string that meets the requirements.

Examples of TypeErrors:

```
>>> int(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    int(None)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number,
 not 'NoneType'
>>> int([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    int([1,2,3])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, 
not 'list'
>>> int(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    int(1,2,3)
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
>>> int((1,2,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    int((1,2,3))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, 
not 'tuple'
```

Using other functions which return the required type will not produce an error.

```
>>> int(max(1.11,6.66,3.33,2.22))
6
>>> int(min(1.11,6.66,3.33,2.22))
1
```